# Interstellar Movie spaceship "The Endurance" would not spin about same center after explosion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum

Although [Interstellar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/) is a movie, they seem to suggest that a connection can be made to the spinning "Endurance" spaceship after one of its 12 modules explodes (due to Dr. Mann). However, this would cause the ship to wobble about its previous center of mass, making a "spinning" connection to it very difficult. Or are we supposed to get the impression that this was accounted for?

Comment: I know the BH stuff was supposed to be mostly realistic for *Interstellar*, but it's still just a movie. There really isn't any need to over-analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a rule of motion that rotation about any axis but the highest or lowest moment of inertia is unstable.  E.g. try to flip a (defunct) mobile phone end over end longways.  So the rotation of the ring-like ship induced by a random impulse may settle into one that is primarily about its axis.